# System.Collections.IDictionary does not contain a definition for "Settings"?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void OnExit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.save();
        }
    }
```

How to fix this? Is there anywhere I need to "register" my settings? The waving line is below Settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Properties.Settings is available against your application. You have to reference the Properties with the Application NameSpace.

```
WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Where `WpfApplication1` is the namespace of your Application.